# 93 toyota camry le 4 cylinder, brake locked up

Tags: toyota, brakes, camry

Ok I've replaced the master cylinder , replaced brakes an brake hoses an the calipers but they still continue to lock up an smoke as I'm driving I've bled the lines they are bleeding just fine. 1993 toyota camry Le 4 cylinder..any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by "lock up"? Did you purchase ceramic pads?

Comment: Are all 4 brakes locking up?

Comment: Does the brake pedal feel any different to usual?